# Create RDS aurora-mysql5.7 via CloudFormation with EnableCloudwatchLogsExports parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-aurora

I've got CloudFormation template that I'm using to create RDS aurora-mysql5.7 cluster.

I'm trying to add EnableCloudwatchLogsExports parameter to it:

```
  RDSCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties: 
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports: 
        - String
```

And there is a question... All my attempts with 'error', 'errors', 'error log' itp. finished with rollback and error message:

> You cannot use the log types 'error logs' with engine version aurora-mysql 5.7.12. For supported log types, see the documentation. (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 16f5c442-6969-44aa-a67e-12f9ca524055)

I'd like to publish Audit, Error, General and Slow query logs to CloudWatch.
I can't find in docs what are the 'allowed' supported values for this property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try out the following:

- Try to specify the log types as follows:

```
RDSCluster:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBCluster
    Properties: 
      EnableCloudwatchLogsExports: 
        - "error"
        - "general"
        - "slowquery"
        - "audit"
```

- Make sure the DB Cluster Parameter Group used has advanced auditing enabled. For example: `server_audit_logging` has value `ON`.
  Reference: [Using Advanced Auditing with an Amazon Aurora MySQL DB Cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Auditing.html)
- If the above 2 approaches didn't work, try to change the MySQL version.

Comment: So that's the allowed values for log type. Of course I pass some additional configuration in custom parameters group. It's working with my current MySQL version! Thank you!